# ¿Por qué esta consulta no muestra los datos esperados?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Estoy haciendo una consulta con php y la tabla que tengo tiene 2 páginas por la cantidad de registros, ahora cuando hago la consulta no me muestra nada, pero si busco por un solo nombre(es decir una sola persona) que tiene como máximo 3 registros en ese caso si obtiene los datos, no se si tiene que ver con la cantidad de filas, porque cuando era una sola página si realizaba la consulta y me mostraba todos los registros.

Este es mi código php para la consulta

```
$conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);

$ins='SELECT * FROM horarios';

$q=mysqli_query($conexion,$ins);

$arreglo=array();

while($respuesta=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
    array_push($arreglo, $respuesta);
}
print json_encode($arreglo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```

Esta es la segunda página de mi tabla

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cuando busco por consultas que tengan pocos registros si me los muestra pero no cuando quiero traer toda la tabla, los muestro en un JSON porque lo necesito así, en este caso la consulta es así:

```
$ins='SELECT * FROM horarios WHERE Entrada="07.30"';
```

Y si me muestra porque son pocos los registros que coinciden
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es una sola tabla que quiero traer pero no me deja, desde que se dividió en 2 páginas

Comment: Muestranos como estan mostrando los datos por pantalla, el codigo completo

Comment: De paso, puedes incluir qué datos estás intentando mostrar (una muestra de prueba al menos), cómo modificas el código para "buscar por un solo nombre" y qué ves en los logs de PHP cuando corres tus consultas

Comment: Deberías ser más explicito, no se entiende con lo que mostrás, ...como es el script del paginado? Que registros de que tablas debés mostrar?....

Comment: CUando dices que _tiene 2 páginas_, ¿te refieres a como se ve en phpMyAdmin? Si es así, eso no tiene relación (puedes cambiar el 25 en el campo número de filas y phpMyAdmin va a paginar diferente, la tabla no tiene páginas). Por favor, revisa los logs de PHP. Ayúdate con [`json_last_error`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php) también.

Comment: Me refiero al hecho de que desde que son más de 22 registros ya no me muestra toda la tabla con la consulta, solo muestra la página en blanco(donde imprimo el resultado de la consulta)

Comment: ENtonces, como te estoy diciendo, eso no significa que haya páginas en la tabla. Eso es cosa del cliente que estás usando. Revisa los logs de PHP por favor y trae los errores relacionados que haya. Usa el método que te sugerí para ver si hay algún tipo de error en el json_encode

Comment: Pon un `var_dump($arreglo);` en tu código y dinos qué muestra. Como bien dice @Alfabravo, las tablas no tienen páginas, en PHPMyAdmin ves los resultados paginados porque es una funcionalidad de ese IDE. Si tú consultas la tabla desde la consola por ejemplo vas a ver todos los resultados seguidos, aunque sean miles de filas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que todo te recomiendo que cambies a PDO de php es mucho mas facil a mi parecer. Hice una prueba con la misma base de datos que tienes y me funciono de la siguiente manera:

*Recuerda que debes cambiar las credenciales de la base de datos, no dejas ver cuales són. Te dejo la documentación de PDO: https://www.php.net/manual/es/book.pdo.php

```
<?php

    class Connection {

        function connectdb() {

            //attributes

            $user = 'root';
            $pass = '';

            global $connect;

            //methods

            // Set DSN

            $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testing;';

            //Create a PDO instance

            try {

                $connect = new PDO($dsn, $user, $pass, array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"));
                $connect->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");


            }catch(PDOexception $e) {

                print 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
                
            }

        }

    }

    $newconnection = new Connection();
    $newconnection->connectdb();
    
    /*$conexion=mysqli_connect($host,$usuario,$clave,$bd);

    $ins='SELECT * FROM horarios';

    $q =mysqli_query($conexion,$ins);

    $arreglo=array();

    while($respuesta=mysqli_fetch_assoc($q)){
        array_push($arreglo, $respuesta);
    }
    print json_encode($arreglo, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
    mysqli_close($conexion);*/

    $result = $connect->prepare("SELECT * FROM horarios");
    if($result->execute()){
        $saveResult = $result->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        print(json_encode($saveResult));
    }

?>
```